# Format number into Text In SSRS

Tags: excel, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

Hi Guys I have a big problem in SSRS 
I have a column in my report name account number
See attached

[image: SSRS Column]

But when I export in excel it looks like this

[image: Excel]

It looks good but when I click the account number the format will look like this

[image]

The Client do not want this kind of format is there any solution on how to maintain the format?

Comment: Have you tried exporting the field as a text/string? This should prevent Excel from displaying it as a number.

Comment: You mean format cells in excel and convert it into text? it's good but the client don't want to do that. This report runs to the server and send the report into email automatically

Comment: No, i mean you can vonvert the field in your SSIS package within the data flow. Excel should then leave the column as text.

Comment: In SSRS, use **CSTR** to convert to a string. `=CStr(<your current field or expression>)`.

Comment: @Mithrandir Im just doing this into ssrs

Comment: @HannoverFist Its still the same when I click into excel the format change even I use CTR and FORMAT

Comment: Unfortunately, this is an Excel issue - it's changing the numbers because Excel is oh-so smart and **knows** you want it in scientific notation. Your only way around may be to add an apostrophe so Excel treats it as text. `="'" & <Your Expression>`

Comment: How is the report used? Is the report accessed by a user, that user sees a table, or clicks on export to excel? If yes, then you can try to copy the table from the webpage, and paste that in excel. What are the cell poperties are of both? If doing some work in the excel is okay, and the zero's in the number are not mandatory, then you could also do: add a '1' to a cell somewhere, copy that cell so that 1 is cached, go to the numbers where your question is about, paste special, paste as multiply (or something like that in English). The targetcells are multiplied by 1 and shown as numbers.

Comment: This is Excel functionality.  To avoid it, tell your users to hit the "Esc" key or Undo button.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how flexible your display requirements are, but adding a non-number value to the output will prevent Excel from re-formatting it as a number.

As @HannoverFist noted you can replace the value `[account_no]` use the expressions `"'" & [account_no]`.  This will ouput like `'00000123124` but will transform to `00000123124` after the user clicks on it.

If your client doesn't like the way that looks before they click on it I would recommend using a different character like `#` so your output looks like `#00000123124`.  This may look reasonable to your client and won't go through any transformation when they click on it.